# What kinds of database server?

Tags: database

I want to make DB but I just know MySQL and PostgreSQL. Can you tell what kind of DB server?
I want to know what DB server for make some web or for make some application (VB, Delphi).

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Please give us more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An absolute plethora:

- DB2
- Oracle (though it still can't distinguish empty string from NULL)
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- SQLServer
- Informix
- Cloudscape
- SQLite
- Berzerkely db (yes, that's the Uni's *true* name)
- Firebird
- Ingres
- Apache Derby
- Teradata
- the NoSQL rabble (lumping all the non-ACIDs together)
- dBase II
- dBase III(+)
- dBase IV
- Access
- FoxPro
- Excel (I know, it's just that all managers *treat* it like one)
- flat files
- XML (yes it can be used as DB)
- Paradox
- Clipper
- Clarion
- R:Base
- DataEase
- DataFlex
- Advanced Revelation

(I may have missed some).

See also the [list of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) on Wikipedia.

Now, do you have a specific *programming* question about any of these?